# Multiple regex patterns on same string Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, string

Suppose that I have a very large string `str` and I need to execute multiple regex patterns on `str`, is there anyway I can do this in javascript such that the total running time depends only on the length of the string but not on the number of regex patters?

i.e. instead of doing the following

```
var match1 = myRegexp1.exec(str);
var match2 = myRegexp2.exec(str);
var match3 = myRegexp3.exec(str);
```

is there any way to execute all the regex patterns at a time on the string.

I found an article http://fulmicoton.com/posts/multiregexp/ which says that there is [re2](https://code.google.com/p/re2/) for C++ and he(the guy who wrote the article) made the library for Java. Is there any such for/in Javascript?

Comment: Do you want to execute them all or fail on the first match/no-match? Are the regular expressions constant? If so what are they?

Comment: @AlexK. I want to execute them all... i am trying to parse the html content of a page with each regex for each case i am having.. and in oe particular execution the regexps are constant

Comment: Parsing HTML with JavaScript is easier when you use DOM :)

Comment: There are better ways of parsing html in JavaScript than RegExs ...

Comment: @Ja͢ck, Alex Hmm yeah but here in my case i only have  some input which would be present inside a div and i need to remove that div

Comment: You're making it seem that's somehow a problem? Could you explain better what exactly it is you're trying to do?

Comment: @Ja͢ck it is like searching for set of words in the page that are to be removed from the page.. so first i am searching for those words in the divs to get the respective div nodes and later deleting those nodes

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you need something like this

```
var rgx = new RegExp([myRegexp1, myRegexp2, myRegexp3].map(function(r){
   return (r+"").replace(/\//g,"");
}).join("|"), "g");
var match = rgx.exec(str);
```

What it does is take your regex and remove delimiters and join it with `|` so it becomes multiple regex and finally add a global flag.

Comment: this isn't working fine if the regex has escape character...
i.e for eg [/\<nllm/, /road/] is being converted as /\\<nllm|road/g instead of /\<nllm|road/g

Comment: not sure why but only the 2nd regex in array is working after merge